# How do i move objects in java game like chess. android programming

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

How to set the touch listener to the basic small pixelled image/game objects and update the position in onTouch with x & y coordinates we get from the event parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the touch listener to your image/gameobject and update the position in onTouch according to the x and y you get from the event parameter.

Comment: Thanks man for helping. It would be great if you can help me with a basic moving program. Like how to redeem the position of an object. The parameters I mean( coordinates ).

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-achieving-movement--mobile-5463

Check this tutorial out first.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it.  Farooq Arshed